# How do I limit a dynamically populated navigation using jQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, limit, blogs

I am using an CMS called Perch and I need to cap the Blog navigation to the last 12 months.  Perch says that I cannot do it on the CMS side.  Is there a way to do it on the front-end side with a jQuery function and CSS?

This is the code that CMS is outputting in the Front-End.

```
<ul>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2013">2013</a>

<ul>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2013&amp;month=06">June</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2013&amp;month=05">May</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2013&amp;month=04">April</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2013&amp;month=03">March</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2013&amp;month=02">February</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2013&amp;month=01">January</a></li>

</ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012">2012</a>

<ul>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=12">December</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=11">November</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=10">October</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=09">September</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=08">August</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=07">July</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=06">June</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=05">May</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=04">April</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=03">March</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=02">February</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2012&amp;month=01">January</a></li>

</ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011">2011</a>

<ul>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=12">December</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=11">November</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=10">October</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=09">September</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=08">August</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=07">July</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=06">June</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=05">May</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=04">April</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=03">March</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=02">February</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2011&amp;month=01">January</a></li>

</ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2010">2010</a>

<ul>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2010&amp;month=11">November</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2010&amp;month=09">September</a></li>

    <li><a href="archive.php?year=2010&amp;month=02">February</a></li>

</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated please!!

Comment: do you have code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's never a good idea to remove data with JS because you can easily prevent that from happening so you should find a way to limit the output with php/ perch.

In jQuery, you could do something like that:

```
$('li:gt(11)').remove();

$('ul').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).children().length) $(this).remove();
});
```